# MPMoviePlayer dismiss when pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer, dismiss

I have a MPMoviePlayer setup to play an intro movie to my application. That works just great, the only problem is that it lasts for 14 seconds, and I want to give my users a chance to skip the intro by pressing anywhere on the movie.

I have hidden the movie controls, as they are not needed.

Code:

```
NSString *introPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mov"];
intro = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:introPath]];
[intro setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
[intro play];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: My initial solution won't work, because the movie is shown in a second window, layered on top of the app's main window (it's very rare to have more than one window in the view hierarchy on the iPhone). This solution, based on [Apple's MoviePlayer sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html), does work:

```
. . .
    // assuming you have prepared your movie player, as in the question
    [self.intro play];

    NSArray* windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    // There should be more than one window, because the movie plays in its own window
    if ([windows count] > 1)
    {
        // The movie's window is the one that is active
        UIWindow* moviePlayerWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        // Now we create an invisible control with the same size as the window
        UIControl* overlay = [[[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:moviePlayerWindow.frame]autorelease];

        // We want to get notified whenever the overlay control is touched
        [overlay addTarget:self action:@selector(movieWindowTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        // Add the overlay to the window's subviews
        [moviePlayerWindow addSubview:overlay];
    }
. . .

// This is the method we registered to be called when the movie window is touched
-(void)movieWindowTouched:(UIControl*)sender
{
    [self.intro stop];
}
```

NB: You must save the reference to the movie player in an instance variable, and it's most convenient to declare a property that we can use to access it. That's why is use `self.intro` instead of just `intro` in the example. If you don't know how to declare an instance variable and a property, there is plenty of information on this site and elsewhere.

**** ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW

(Doesn't work in this case, but in many similar scenarios, so I'll leave it as a warning and/or inspiring example.)

. . . if nothing else works I'd recommend subclassing UIWindow and making sure that your app delegate instantiates that instead of a normal UIWindow. You can intercept touches in that class and send a notification or cancel the movie directly (if you've stored a pointer to the MPMoviePlayer in an ivar on your window subclass).

```
@interface MyWindow : UIWindow {
}
@end

@implementation MyWindow
// All touch events get passed through this method
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // The screen has been touched, send a notification or stop the movie
   return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

Comment: That's fine. And if you'd like further clarification, please let me know which part you didn't understand, or which part you did understand, or how familiar you are with UIKit.

Comment: I am fairly new to iPhone developing, so I'm not really familiar with UIKit at all.
But it's late at night here where I live, so I'll wite some more tomorrow, ok?

Comment: Perfect. We're in the same time zone :)

Comment: Ah, ok :p

Ok, here's the thing. I have got a tab bar app. When it launches, in the AppDelegate files, I play the intro video.
How do you implement the code you wrote in that?

Comment: Code:



       - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 
 NSString *introPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"mov"];
 intro = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:introPath]];
 [intro setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
 [intro play];
}

Comment: @Emil: See edit. Create an instance variable and property in your app delegate, so you can save the pointer to the movie player.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly :) I did not have to use the `self.intro` either.